# Standing at attention, up straight, but not actually saluting—what verb for what Sam the Eagle is doing in The Muppet Christmas Carol?

Tags: single-word-requests

In *The Muppet Christmas Carol*, Sam the Eagle plays the role of Scrooge’s headmaster from his school days, as seen when Scrooge is visited by the Ghost of Christmas Past. When the young Scrooge graduates, Sam has an amusing scene in which he acts in a very particular way every time he says the word “business.”

For example:

[image: Sam standing up solemnly as he says the word “business”]

Sam does this a couple of times for the word “business,” and then does it even more strongly when he says “the American Way!” as well as when he hastily corrects himself to “the British Way!”

The verb I want to use for this action is “salute,” but he doesn’t actually salute. When he gets to “the American Way” and “the British Way,” he puts his hand over his heart, so that could be a salute, but with “business” he doesn’t. He just stands up straight and tall, like a soldier coming to attention. “Clicking his heels” also comes to mind, though there is no audible “click” (there might be a bit of a stomp?), and anyway that’s a phrase rather than a verb, and potentially not a very well-known one?

Comment: Haven't you answered the question yourself?  Sam *stands to attention and puts his right hand over his heart.* And no, that's not a single word which is why I'm commenting, not answering.

Comment: "Standing at attention" is not saluting.

Comment: @HotLicks That’s my point, he doesn’t actually salute. So what do we call what he _does_ do?

Comment: He stands at attention.

Answer (score 3):

Sam "draws himself up, and says..."

[Farlex](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/draw+(oneself)+up) has

> **draw (oneself) up**
>
> 1. To stand up straight, as tall as one can.
> 2. To stand up straight in a show of indignation.

I don't know what Sam says, but he poses himself for an important announcement.

Answer (score -1):

A single-word answer could be **bristle**.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bristle) has

> **bristle** *intransitive verb*
> **1** to rise and stand stiffly erect
> **2** to take on an aggressively defensive attitude
> *he bristled at the accusations of corruption*

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bristle) has

> **bristle** *verb*
> to react angrily
> *She bristled at the suggestion that she had in any way neglected the child.*

Comment: Bristle definitely does not mean this. Even in the M-W definition 1 (which I do not think should be first), the physical act is a defensive, angry one. Sam’s behavior isn’t remotely that. I upvoted your other suggestion but I think this one is wrong.

Comment: The first verb meaning in M-W is what Sam is doing, closer than Cambridge. This was the closest 'single-word' answer I could find.